# h2o ensemble throws error: "Base model does not keep cross-validation predictions"

Tags: python, h2o, ensemble-learning

I'm trying to create an ensemble model in H2O from a number of GLM, GBM, and deep learning models.

Here's what I did so far.

Import relevant libraries:

```
import h2o
from h2o.estimators.glm import H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator
from h2o.estimators.gbm import H2OGradientBoostingEstimator
from h2o.estimators.deeplearning import H2ODeepLearningEstimator
from h2o.estimators.stackedensemble import H2OStackedEnsembleEstimator
from h2o.grid.grid_search import H2OGridSearch
```

The data can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/data/allyears2k.csv). Import:

```
airlines = h2o.import_file(path = "/Users/alexwoolford/h2o/allyears2k.csv", destination_frame = "airlines.hex")
```

Split into training/test sets:

```
airlines_80,airlines_20 = airlines.split_frame(ratios=[.8], destination_frames=["airlines_80.hex", "airlines_20.hex"])
```

Define variables (predict y as a function of all the columns in x):

```
x= airlines.columns
y= "ArrDelay"
x.remove(y)
```

Set common properties:

```
folds=5
assignment_type="Modulo"
search_criteria={'strategy': 'RandomDiscrete', 'max_models': 5, 'seed': 1}
```

Use H2O's grid search to create a variety of models:

```
# GLM
glm_params = {"alpha": [0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.],
              "lambda": [0, 1e-7, 1e-5, 1e-3, 1e-1]}

glm_grid = H2OGridSearch(model=H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(fold_assignment=assignment_type, nfolds=folds),
                         grid_id='glm_grid',
                         hyper_params=glm_params,
                         search_criteria=search_criteria)
glm_grid.train(x=x,
               y=y,
               training_frame=airlines_80,
               validation_frame=airlines_20)

# GBM
gbm_params = {'learn_rate': [0.01, 0.03],
              'max_depth': [3, 4, 5, 6, 9],
              'sample_rate': [0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1],
              'col_sample_rate': [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8]}

gbm_grid = H2OGridSearch(model=H2OGradientBoostingEstimator(fold_assignment=assignment_type, nfolds=folds),
                         grid_id='gbm_grid',
                         hyper_params=gbm_params,
                         search_criteria=search_criteria)
gbm_grid.train(x=x,
               y=y,
               training_frame=airlines_80,
               validation_frame=airlines_20)

# Deep learning
dl_params = {'activation': ['rectifier', 'rectifier_with_dropout'],
             'hidden': [[10,10], [20,15], [50,50,50]],
             'l1': [0, 1e-3, 1e-5],
             'l2': [0, 1e-3, 1e-5]}

dl_grid = H2OGridSearch(model=H2ODeepLearningEstimator(fold_assignment=assignment_type, nfolds=folds),
                        grid_id='dl_grid',
                        hyper_params=dl_params,
                        search_criteria=search_criteria)

dl_grid.train(x=x,
              y=y,
              training_frame=airlines_80,
              validation_frame=airlines_20)
```

Get list of all the model_id's:

```
all_model_ids = glm_grid.model_ids + gbm_grid.model_ids + dl_grid.model_ids
```

Where I try to create an ensemble:

```
ensemble = H2OStackedEnsembleEstimator(base_models=all_model_ids)
ensemble.train(x=x, y=y, training_frame=airlines_80, validation_frame=airlines_20)
```

... the following error is thrown:

```
stackedensemble Model Build progress: | (failed)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-bc7b6094816f> in <module>()
      1 ensemble = H2OStackedEnsembleEstimator(base_models=all_model_ids)
----> 2 ensemble.train(x=x, y=y, training_frame=airlines_80, validation_frame=airlines_20)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/estimators/estimator_base.py in train(self, x, y, training_frame, offset_column, fold_column, weights_column, validation_frame, max_runtime_secs, ignored_columns, model_id, verbose)
    235             return
    236 
--> 237         model.poll(verbose_model_scoring_history=verbose)
    238         model_json = h2o.api("GET /%d/Models/%s" % (rest_ver, model.dest_key))["models"][0]
    239         self._resolve_model(model.dest_key, model_json)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h2o/job.py in poll(self, verbose_model_scoring_history)
     75             if (isinstance(self.job, dict)) and ("stacktrace" in list(self.job)):
     76                 raise EnvironmentError("Job with key {} failed with an exception: {}\nstacktrace: "
---> 77                                        "\n{}".format(self.job_key, self.exception, self.job["stacktrace"]))
     78             else:
     79                 raise EnvironmentError("Job with key %s failed with an exception: %s" % (self.job_key, self.exception))

OSError: Job with key $03017f00000132d4ffffffff$_a2359a38ec8d31316aee91398f0249f8 failed with an exception: water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException: Base model does not keep cross-validation predictions: 5
stacktrace: 
water.exceptions.H2OIllegalArgumentException: Base model does not keep cross-validation predictions: 5
    at hex.StackedEnsembleModel.checkAndInheritModelProperties(StackedEnsembleModel.java:382)
    at hex.ensemble.StackedEnsemble$StackedEnsembleDriver.computeImpl(StackedEnsemble.java:234)
    at hex.ModelBuilder$Driver.compute2(ModelBuilder.java:218)
    at water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1395)
    at jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1477)
    at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

Can you seem what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This should not happen since by default we keep the CV predictions (and you have not turned that off).  What version of H2O are you using?  If it's not the latest stable, can you upgrade and try again?  I remember we turned off saving CV preds by default in grid search for a brief amount of time but then realized the issue and fixed it, so I am hoping if you upgrade that will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Erin. It's an honor: I was just watching one of your presentations on YouTube. I'm using H2O version 3.22.1.2 which, according to the output from `h2o.init()` is 15 days old. I'll see if a more recent version is available. Alos, I took a peek at the models in Flow and see that cross-validation models are there (e.g. `dl_grid_model_1`, `dl_grid_model_1_cv_1`, `dl_grid_model_1_cv_2`, etc...

Comment: @Erin: FYI... I updated H2O to the latest and greatest version, currently 3.22.1.3, and experienced the same error. I'll try and figure it out what's happening here.

Comment: Lauren solved it below... I forgot that `keep_cross_validation_predictions` is turned off in regular H2O algorithms by default (I was thinking of H2O AutoML, in which it's turned on by default).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the parameter `keep_cross_validation_predictions=True` in each of your models. For example you would want to do the following for your GLM and then likewise for the other models you want to stack:

```
glm_grid = H2OGridSearch(model=H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(fold_assignment=assignment_type, nfolds=folds,
    keep_cross_validation_predictions=True),
                                 grid_id='glm_grid',
                                 hyper_params=glm_params,
                                 search_criteria=search_criteria)
```

Comment: Thanks @Lauren. I should have read the docs more carefully (see second bullet point in http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/stacked-ensembles.html#training-base-models-for-the-ensemble)